# How to make the volume control to control the notification volume?

Tags: android, notifications, volume, preference

I have an app has volume preference, I will use it to control notification volume. Below my layout code:

```
<VolumePreference
    android:name="Volume Preference"
    android:summary="Notification Volume"
    android:title="Notification Volume"
    android:key="notifVolPref"/>
```

But I don't know, How to implement that on class?

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to use setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION) in your onCreate?  Or am I missing what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, but it just work if I press an analog volume control on phone. Now I will implement it in preference screen on my setting. Can u help me?